# WooCommerce Plugin Not Showing

Tags: php, woocommerce

I've bought a plugin which has a product table for the product page, however it doesn't show on the product page. I put the website into debug mode and this came up.

Notice: Undefined index: price_table_on in /www/eroofingcouk_311/public/wp-content/plugins/elex-woocommerce-dynamic-pricing-and-discounts-premium/public/elex-dynamic-pricing-plugin-public.php on line 183

```
function elex_dp_show_pricing_table() {
    $selected_role=get_option('elex_dp_allowed_roles_to_show_pricing_table');
    if(!empty($selected_role) ) {
            $user = wp_get_current_user();
            if(!count(array_intersect($user->roles, $selected_role)) > 0) {
                return;
            }
    }
    $path= dirname(__FILE__) ."/elex-single-product-pricing-table.php";
    if ($GLOBALS['settings']['price_table_on_off'] == 'enable' && file_exists($path) == true ) {
        include "elex-single-product-pricing-table.php";
    }
```

Line 183 is ***if ($GLOBALS['settings']['price_table_on_off'] == 'enable' && file_exists($path) == true ) {***
I was wondering if anyone had any idea what the issue is with it and how to fix it?

Comment: if it concerns a purchased plugin, have you already contacted the creators of the plugin?